# Sci-fi book with a generational spaceship traveling the interstellar void

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, space, generation-ship, black-hole

Spaceship is gigantic.  Most of the passengers don’t even realize that it’s a spaceship and the Author describes the world in great - captivating - detail.  The ship has forests, lakes and generally presents as a planet.  There are various levels and there is indeed a crew.

The passengers are humans for the most part.

Muddled recollection that it uses Micro blackholes for propulsion.  It comes under siege.  The protagonist, a young girl aspiring to become the captain is the one that must gather resources – personnel and material – to help save the ship. The girl is an apprentice in engineering (or somewhere in the crew).

The ship is chased by planetesimals.  The ship is wounded by repeated attacks but it must get somewhere to find safe harbor.

Will add more details as and when I able to recollect.

Not too old.  Paperback.  Released in 2000s, I would reckon.  Might have been borrowed from my library around 2013.  The front cover has planets / depicts the chase (I think).

Never finished the book so can’t really say much about how it ends.

Please help find the book.

Comment: More details please! Any idea when it was written? Are the passengers humans? If so, are they originally from Earth? Are they heading to a destination system, or do they just intend to live in space indefinitely?  Etc.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Did you actually mean "plantesimals" as in mini-planetoids formed from accumulated dust and debris? They sound much more active than that.

Comment: Ditto with "the ship is wounded". Does that mean the ship is alive, Moya-like?

Comment: planetesimal question:  Meant it planet-like.  As in: chased by a small moon.  Something spherical and non-artificial but apparently artificial as it moves on it’s own power.

Comment: The author describes the ship like a living thing: a benevolent Gaia.

Comment: YA fiction? No-one who wants to be captain goes into engineering.

Comment: Very tentative ID so posting as comment: one of the Great Ship series? https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/GreatShip

Comment: @OrganicMarble Wow!  This looks like it.  I think the “the nearly indestructible hyper fiber hull” is attacked at some point using micro black holes.  Will confirm soon and you can post it as answer.   Thank you.

Comment: @OrganicMarble: Please post this as answer and I'll accept it.  I'm reading Marrow - book #1 - now. I am not sure which book I was referring to (#1 or #2 in the series).  However, it's this universe.  So, a BIG thank you!

Comment: Super. will do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look like my wild guess was correct. OP confirmed that they were looking for the [Great Ship](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/GreatShip) series by [Robert Reed](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?12285):

> In the distant future, an enormous ship larger than many worlds is
> discovered streaking towards the Milky Way at a third the speed of
> light. The near-immortal, TransHuman descendants of humanity are the
> first set foot on the enormous ship, and the first to claim it. The
> ancient reactors are warmed up, and life is nurtured inside the
> millions of enormous caverns inside the ship's hull. A burst from the
> moon-sized engines catapults the ship around a brown dwarf, setting it
> into the galactic plane, where humanity sells berths on the Great Ship
> in exchange for worlds, information, and technology. The nearly
> indestructible hyperfiber hull makes the Great Ship Nigh Invulnerable,
> a very desirable feature to the nearly immortal, fantastically rich
> sentient entities in the galaxy, who desire something safer than a
> planet to reside on. Technology, colonization rights, pledges of
> assistance, and information is sold for the right to reside on the
> Ship.Tens of thousands of species reside in the Great Ship, some
> interacting in the enormous cities and ports, others secluding
> themselves in distant caverns and empty fuel tanks.

(warning, first link is to TVTropes)

Comment: But which one of them?

Comment: @Valorum Is that fuzzy enough?

Comment: I recall one of them had a siege on the surface of the ship. Basically there was no way in for x hundred years and those on the outside were just as trapped as those on the inside

Comment: @Valorum Yes, most likely it was the siege book I was referring to.  I am only at 10% so can’t confirm if the first one is the one.  Don’t want the books spoiled for me.  So, I have accepted the answer.  